# Powershell script to send out emails read from a CSV/Excel file with a specific attachment

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, export-to-excel

Currently working on a script that gathers all owners email address' within an Azure AD group and exports them as a TXT/CSV file as names the file as the group name for a security audit. For example, GroupName.csv contains, Owner1@domain.com,Owner2@domain.com etc.
I want to write a script that will send out emails to the group owners listed in the .csv file but send out an attachment of a list of group members, that are also saved as GroupName.csv, that is already saved in a different folder. So, each group owner can validate if the group member belongs in that group. This is what I have found so far online. Can anyone help me amend it to fit my needs. I’m new to PowerShell so very basic understanding. Apologies if this is hard to understand.
My organisation uses outlook FYI.

```
\#This is what I’ve written so far to export a list of groupowners and save them as their #groupnames, this works fine, but make any amendments necessary
$cred = Get-Credential Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
ForEach($group in $groups) {
    $resultsarray = @()
    $owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true
    ForEach($owner in $owners) {
        $resultsarray += \[PSCustomObject\] @{" " = $owner.UserPrincipalName}
        $gName = $group.DisplayName[IO.Path]::GetinvalidFileNameChars() |
        ForEach - Object{$gName = $gName.Replace(
                             $_, "_")}[IO.Path] ::GetinvalidFileNameChars() |
        ForEach - Object{$gName = $gName.Replace(
                             '[', "_")}[IO.Path] ::GetinvalidFileNameChars() |
        ForEach - Object{$gName = $gName.Replace(']', "_")}

    #$resultsarray | Export-CSV -Path D :\\Script\\AzureADOwners$gName.csv -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation

    $resultsarray | Out-File -Filepath D:\\Script\\AzureADOwners$gName.txt
    }
}
```

```
\#This what I've found online. The path of the CSV's of owners is D:\\Script\\AzureADOwners\\ and all #csv files are named as the GroupName.csv.

Import-Module ImportExcel
$csv_files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\\Script\\AzureADOwners' -Filter '\*.csv'
foreach ($csv_file in $csv_files) {
    $data = Import-Csv -Path $csv_file.FullName
    foreach ($row in $data) {
        $email_address = $row.Column1
        $attachment = D:\Script\AzureADMembers\$csv_file.csv
        Send-MailMessage -To $email_address -Subject 'Test Email' -Body 'This is a test email.' -Attachments $attachment -SmtpServer 'smtp.gmail.com' -Credential(Get-Credential)
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue/problem? The `Send-MailMessage` function takes the argument `-Attachments`, not `-Attachment`. You also probably need to specify the correct Port and use the `-UseSsl` switch.

Comment: What error are you receiving when you run the second script?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the scenario in my environment:***

*I used below powershell code:*

- First got group owners.From that exported csv of owners and collected
  mail id of each owner.
- For each owner, requested group members and  stored in another csv to
  attacht to  the mail

**Powershell code:**

```
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
ForEach($group in $groups) {
    $resultsarray = @()
    $owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true

$owners | foreach-object {
$owner = $_

$u_properties = [pscustomobject] @{
"groupName"=$group.DisplayName
"UserPrincipalName" = $owner.UserPrincipalName 
"Country" = $owner.Displayname 
"Email"=$owner.Mail
"GroupId" =$group.ObjectId
}



$path='D:\ownersFile.csv'
# check
write-host "got $u_properties"

 $u_properties | Export-csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -Force -Append


 $ExportedOwnerdata = Import-Csv -Path $path
 }

 #members
 $members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId


$members | foreach-object {
$member = $_
write-host "got $member_properties"
 
$member_properties = [pscustomobject] @{
"groupName"=$group.DisplayName
"member" = $member.UserPrincipalName 
"memberDisplayName" = $member.Displayname 
}

#stroring mebers in csv in another local file
$mempath='D:\AzureADMembers.csv'
write-host "got $memer_properties"
 $member_properties| Export-csv -Path $mempath -NoTypeInformation -Force -Append

#getting owners data from already exported file
$wholedata= Import-Csv -Path 'D:\ownersFile.csv'
$data.UserPrincipalName  
$data.Email


$FileContent = get-content $mempath
foreach ($data in $wholedata)
{
#getting mail of each owner
$email_address=$data.Email | Sort-Object | Get-Unique
$email_address
$attachment=D:\AzureADMembers.csv
#Send-MailMessage -To $myemail  -Subject 'Test Email' -Body 'This is a test email.' -Attachments $mempath  -SmtpServer 'smtp.gmail.com' -Credential(Get-Credential)


}
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

owners file with mails:

[image]

members:

[image]

Reference : [send-mailmessage | Microsoft learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: I'll give this ago! Thanks. That's essentially what I am trying to do! Does it work when you try to email and send it out?

Comment: I haven't sent the mail using above commands as it was obselete as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.3#description) and getting smtp error . Check  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-send-email) too.